# Android SeekBar Touch Sensitivity

Tags: android, touch, android-seekbar

Recently I have been working on an app which has a `SeekBar`. The `SeekBar` is rather thin so it can at times be difficult to use it (you have to be very precise in your gestures). Is there any way to increase the touchable area of the `SeekBar`? So I want users to be able to touch above or below the `SeekBar` to move the thumb. I'd appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One of the most straightforward approaches is to increase a value of the `android:padding` attribute:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/yourSeekBar"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/your_topPadding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/your_bottomPadding" />
```

Another possibility: make a custom thumb and increase its background's size by adding e.g.  transparent border.

In addition, [there](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-custom-seekbar-example.html) you have a nice tutorial describing a custom `SeekBar` creation.

Comment: Well that was easy! Adding the padding at the top and bottom worked like a charm!

Comment: If the containing view is large enough, you can also set negative margins to compensate for the padding so it doesn't mess up your layout, assuming you don't have other touchable widgets in the enlarged area.